# Export XElement to Excel

Tags: c#, xml, excel, c#-4.0

Suppose I have following List of `Log` objects and want to export the list to Excel. I would like to convert `List<Log>` to excel. I could manual create the Dataset, but is there a smarter way?

```
String xml1 = "<CustomerPricing><Id>673</Id><Customer>3</Customer><Code>XV1</Code><PricingType>20</PricingType><Discount>33</Discount><Company>10</Company></CustomerPricing>";
String xml2 = "<CustomerPricing><Id>674</Id><Customer>3</Customer><Code>XV1</Code><PricingType>30</PricingType><Discount>35</Discount><Company>10</Company></CustomerPricing>";

Log log1 = new Log { ModifiedBy = "user", DateModified = DateTime.Now, ChangedData = XElement.Parse(xml1) };
Log log2 = new Log { ModifiedBy = "user", DateModified = DateTime.Now, ChangedData = XElement.Parse(xml2) };

List<Log> logs = new List<Log> { log1, log2 };
```

Class:

```
public class Log {

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public String ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public XElement ChangedData { get; set; }
}
```

My Excel Spreadsheet would look something like (each row):

```
DateModified | ModifiedBy | CustomerPricing | Id | Customer | Code
```

Comment: Are you using the OpenXML way of doing things, or the Excel Interop?

Comment: Neither at this point, but I am up for ideas.

Comment: Is dumping to a CSV file an option? If so, I got a real quick cut and dry answer for you. If not, I'll dig up my recent project I did with OpenXML.

Comment: Yes - It can be CSV :) - I like easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a CSV will suffice, here is a quick way to dump out your data:

```
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\yourfile.csv"))
        {
            string header = "DateModified,ModifiedBy,CustomerPricing,Id,Customer,Code";
            writer.WriteLine(header);
            foreach (var log in logs)
            {
                string line = "\"" + log.DateModified.ToShortDateString() + "\",\"" + log.ModifiedBy + "\",\"" +
                              // you don't have a CustomerPricing element, as the whole object is CustomerPricing
                              // add a "Price" element and sub out the element value below
                              //log.ChangedData.Element("CustomerPricing").Value + "\",\"" +
                              log.ChangedData.Element("Id").Value + "\",\"" +
                              log.ChangedData.Element("Customer").Value + "\",\"" +
                              log.ChangedData.Element("Code").Value + "\"";

                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }

        }
```

This has some drawbacks as-is. If you data has weird characters, it will mess up the CSV. You will want to use a CSV library to cleanly write it out. Use the .Element("whatever") method to scoop the values out of your XElement.